# Vim multi-line substitute/insert once on selected text

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, substitute

I tried to make a function

```
function! WrapSelect (front, back)
    "puts characters around the selected text.
    execute '''<, ''>s/\%V\(\_.*\)\%V\(\_.\)/'.a:front.'\1\2'.a:back.'/'
    nohl
endfunction
vnoremap <C-l> :call WrapSelect('[',']')<cr>
```

The reason there's a second group is to make it behave like yank: I want to put the brackets around the selected text, including the character under the cursor, the way yank copies selected text.

Example input (where | denotes highlighted section):

```
a|nd then some words
and some other wor|ds
```

Expected output

```
a[nd then some words
and some other wor]ds
```

Actual output: an error message:

```
 Error detected while processing function WrapSelect:
 line   15:
 E19: Mark has invalid line number
 Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

and the text becomes

```
 a[nd then some words
 and some other wor][ds
 ]
```

With more lines in the file unselected the output becomes more garbage:

```
a[[nd then some words
and some other wor][ds
third line
]
fifth line
]sixth line
```

Reading about substitute says that it does the search on each line in the selected range, and I don't see a way to turn that off and just do it on the whole block once.

I also saw [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15482/17205) that there's a visual mode command I could possibly use, and you can [make visual commands work with functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5084487/5889131), so I tried:

```
function! WrapSelect (front, back)
    "puts characters around the selected text.
    execute "normal gv" . 'c'.a:front.'^R"'.a:back
endfunction
vnoremap <C-l> :call WrapSelect('[',']')<cr>
```

where ^R is the literal C-r from Ctrl+v Ctrl+r (it didn't paste into SE)

This produces different wrong output:

```
a[[nd then some words]
and some other wor]ds
```

This one seemed more promising from reading the help docs (`:h v_c`, `:h i_CTRL-R`), but still did not do what I expected.

I know plugins exist that can do cooler things than I can, but I would like to understand how to do this from my `vimrc` if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a number of ways to do this but I'll just focus on what you tried.

First, there is a fundamental problem with the mappings. If you have visually selected text when the command line is opened with `:` the selection's line range, `'<,'>`, will be automatically inserted. You won't notice this when it's used in a mapping but it's there and it will interfere with the function's logic. Solution:

```
vnoremap <C-l> :<C-U>call WrapSelect('[',']')<cr>
```

Upon opening the command line, before inserting anything we clear any existing text with Ctrl-U by way of the equivalent keycode `<C-U>`.

On to the function code. Using your second approach I tweaked a couple things and it worked fine:

```
execute 'norm! gvc' . a:front. "\<C-R>\""  . a:back
```

I'm using `norm!` to ensure there are no user mappings interfering with what we want to do. And I'm using `<C-R>` instead of `Ctrl-V`+`Ctrl-R`. If you look at the [help for `:execute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#:exe) you'll find this...

```
        ":execute" is also a nice way to avoid having to type
        control characters in a Vim script for a ":normal"
        command: 
    :execute "normal ixxx\<Esc>"
```

The backslash before the keycode is required per [expression strings](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-quote) where it also says "double quotes [must be] used" (which also means we need to escape the double quote signifying the `"` register).

Besides, keycodes are more readable and less error prone than Ctrl-V sequences.

Comment: Did this work for you in a function on multiple lines? It does not work for me on vim 7.4 in that setup.

Comment: @jeremysprofile What does "does not work" mean? I tested it using your examples. I doubt I'm doing anything involving a post 7.4 change though I'll try to find an installation of that version and check it there. I recommend you rule out any local changes by testing with plugins disabled (`vim --noplugin`) and without your personal config (`vim -u NONE`).

Comment: I have no plugins installed. your command works from the command line, but does not seem to work from a test vimrc file that only contains the function and the hotkey. When it fails, it creates too many brackets similar to my existing bind. I will do more testing.

Comment: @jeremysprofile Try adding `<C-U>` to the beginning of your mapping right after the `:`. Pretty sure that's your main problem now that I think about it.

Comment: Does it work for you with `nnoremap` instead of `vnoremap`? (I'm not in front of Vim right now.) Maybe with `<ESC>` before the `:`? Since you are using `gv` might as well deselect visual selection in all cases.

Comment: Hey. it was definitely the <C-u> thing. I dunno what I did to mess it up when I tried testing it when you said it the first time. Works now. Thanks for your help.